# How do you extract a specific line from block of text and store them into string variables?

Tags: bash

**[Bash Scripting]** - I'm working with an LG device and I'm trying to obtain a concatenated Device ID string. I've figured out how to concatenate strings, but I'm having trouble extracting the strings from the overall output. From the bootloader, I run **fastboot oem device-id** and get an output like this. Everything after the "|" was actually outputed, I only included the **"# | "** as line references.

```
1 | ...
2 | (bootloader) ----------------------------------
3 | (bootloader) Device-ID
4 | (bootloader) ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH12345678
5 | (bootloader) 87654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA
6 | (bootloader) ----------------------------------
7 | OKAY [  0.070s]
8 | finished. total time: 0.070s
```

Seems like **fastboot oem device-id** is a little restricted. Using grep with the command only displayed the same content. (**fastboot oem device-id | grep bootloader -m 2**) This should only display the first 2 lines (example). I also tried to output all the content to an external text file (and work from there), but it created a text blank file. (**fastboot oem device-id >> test.txt**)

Ideally, I would like to extract the contents of Lines 4 and 5, and store them into separate string variables - **stringA** and **stringB**, respectively. Strings A and B should output the following

```
(stringA) <-- "(bootloader) ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH12345678" (Line 4)
(stringB) <-- "(bootloader) 87654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA" (Line 5)
```

Then I would concatenate them like this.

```
echo "Device ID:  $(stringA:13:32)$(stringB:13:32)"
```

Starting at column 13 (above) would exclude the **(bootloader)_** part and leave only the desired string. In the end, the output of the echo (above) should look like this.

```
Device ID:  ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH1234567887654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA
```

Strangely, I was able to do all of the above using a different fastboot command (**fastboot devices**). **What other ways are there to extract the strings from Lines 4 and 5 (above) and store them into two separate string variables?**

Comment: So basically you want those strings to  be combined into one? and print it as `Device ID: <str>` right?

Comment: @Inian: Yes, I've figured out how to combine the strings into one. I tried it with a hard-coded stringA and stringB. I'm trying to extract only Lines 4 and 5 and put them into separate strings.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using awk

```
$ fastboot oem device-id | awk 'NR==4{a=$2} NR==5{b=$2; printf "Device ID:  %s%s\n",a,b; exit}'
Device ID:  ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH1234567887654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA
```

How it works:

- `NR==4{a=$2}`

  When we get to the fourth line, save the second field in the variable `a`.
- `NR==5{b=$2; printf "Device ID:  %s%s\n",a,b; exit}`

  When we get to the fifth line, save the second field in variable `b` and write the output line.

#### Using sed

```
$ fastboot oem device-id | sed -n 's/.* //; 4h; 5{H; x; s/\n//; s/^/Device ID:  /p}'
Device ID:  ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH1234567887654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA
```

How it works:

- `-n`

  Tell sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `s/.* //`

  Find all characters up to and including the last space on the line and delete them.
- `4h

  If we are on the fourth line, save what's left to the hold space.
- `5{H; x; s/\n//; s/^/Device ID:  /p}`

  If we are on the fifth line, append what's left of the line to the hold space (`H`).  Swap the hold space with the pattern space (`x`).  Remove the newline any newline character (`s/\n//`).  Add the string `Device ID:` to the beginning of the pattern space and print it (`s/^/Device ID:  /p`).

#### Using bash and grep

```
$ fastboot oem device-id | grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]{32}$' | { read a; read b; echo "Device ID:  $a$b"; }
Device ID:  ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH1234567887654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA
```

How it works:

- `grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]{32}$'`

  If the line from fastboot ends with 32 alphanumeric characters, print those characters.

  In more detail, the `-o` option tells `grep` to only print the matching part of a line.  `-E` tells grep to use extended regex.  `[[:alnum:]]{32}` matches 32 alphanumeric characters.  `$` matches only at the end of the line.
- `read a; read b; echo "Device ID:  $a$b";`

  The first output line from `grep` is read into variable `a`.  The second output line is read into variable `b`.  Then, the desired line is echoed to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the output in a textfile `output.txt` such as:

```
user@host:~$ cat output.txt 
...
(bootloader) ----------------------------------
(bootloader) Device-ID
(bootloader) ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH12345678
(bootloader) 87654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA
(bootloader) ----------------------------------
OKAY [  0.070s]
finished. total time: 0.070s
```

The following command:

```
cat output.txt | sed -n '4,5p' | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\n'
```

- keep the 4th and 5th lines
- keep the second column only
- remove the newline

Thus it finally gives:

> ABCDEFGH12345678ABCDEFGH1234567887654321HGFEDCBA87654321HGFEDCBA

Of course, this one works as well:

```
cat output.txt | sed -n '4,5p' | cut -d\  -f2 | tr -d '\n'
```