# Unable to extract fastboot command with awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, debian-based

I am writing a short script to collect the Android Phone information with fastboot.

With following command

```
    fastboot getvar product
```

I can get return value like this

```
    product: "name"
    Finished. Total time: 0.029s
```

I only need the value "name" after the string "product:" so I try to use ":" as separator. I try to use the suggestion from this thread "[How do you extract a specific line from block of text and store them into string variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026822/how-do-you-extract-a-specific-line-from-block-of-text-and-store-them-into-string/45027024#45027024)" with something similar

```
    fastboot getvar product | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'
```

Or

```
    fastboot getvar product | awk =F ":" '{print $2}'
```

Or

```
    fastboot getvar product | sed -n 's/.* //; 1h'
```

The return value is always

```
    product: "name"
    Finished. Total time: x.xxxs
```

The OS I am using is Debian rodete. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `awk -F: 'NR==1{print $2}'` should work.

Comment: Presumably awk 2 `=F` is typo for `-F` and sed `1h` is meant to be `1p` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `fastboot` (whatever that is!) is printing the output you want to parse to stderr, not stdout. Try:

```
fastboot getvar product 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Yes, it does. [`fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", label.c_str(), value.c_str());`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/master/fastboot/fastboot.cpp#792)